# Shortest path in a complement graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I had a test today (Data Structures course), and one of the questions was the following:
Given an undirected, non-weighted graph G=(V,E), you need to write an algorithm that for a given node s, returns the shortest path from s to all the nodes v' in the complement graph.

A Complement Graph G'=(E',V') contains an edge between any to nodes in G that don't share an edge, and only those.

The algorithm needs to run in O(V+E) (of the original graph).

I asked 50 different students, and not even one of them solved it correctly.

any Ideas?
Thanks a lot,
Barak.

Comment: Hi, you can be sure I have used my brain for two hours for it, during the test, plus four more after it. It's not homework, just pure curiosity.

Comment: I agree with Okuma in that your question is better suited to a different Stack Exchange site. I recommend: [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be O(V+E) of the original graph? You could have a very very sparse graph that will result in a super dense complement  where O(V'+E') would be larger than O(V+E)

Comment: Yes, @miky I'm sure about it. with O(V'+E') it's quite simple.

Comment: I'm assuming the graph is given as adjacency lists otherwise you would always need O(V^2) and in that case proving that O(V'+E') is in O(V+E) is pretty simple. If the graph is given as adjacency lists then proving that O(V'+E') is in O(V+E) is a bit more difficult.

Comment: @MikyDinescu Indeed it's impossible. Of O(E) = O(V), then O(E') = O(V^2).

Comment: @dinescu I asked the professor during the test and he told me I can use either adjacency list or a matrix.

Comment: @Bobcat100 hopefully you'll share your proferssor's solution with us here. I noticed Evgeny's answer below but I must confess, I'm not sold..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The course staff have published the official answers to the test.

The answer is:

"The algorithm is based on a BFS with a few adaptations.
For each node in the graph we will add 2 fields - next and prev. Using these two fields we can maintain two Doubly-Linked lists of nodes: L1,L2.
At the beginning of every iteration of the algorithm, L1 has all the while nodes in the graph, and L2 is empty.
The BFS code (without the initialization) is:

[image: The Algorithm]

At the ending of the loop at lines 3-5, L1 contains all the white nodes that aren't adjacent to u in G, or in other words, all the white nodes that are adjacent to u in the complement graph.
Therefore the runtime of the algorithm equals to the runtime of the original BFS on the complement graph.
The time is O(V+E) because lines 4-5 are executed at most 2E times, and lines 7-9 are executed at most V times (Every node can get out of L1 only once)."

Note: this is the original solution translated from Hebrew.

I Hope you find it helpful, and thank you all for helping me out,

Barak.

Comment: @Miky Dinescu - as you requested. Thank's a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a different approach.

**Initialization:-**

1. Create a list of undiscovered edges. Let's call it `undiscovered` and initialize it with all nodes.
2. Then we will run a modified version of BFS
3. Create a Queue(Q) and add start node to it

**Main algo**

while undiscovered.size()>0 && Queue not Empty

1. `curr_node` = DEQUEUE(Queue)
2. create a list of all edges in the complement graph(Lets call it
   `complement_edges`). This can be created by looping through all the
   nodes in `undiscovered` and checking whether it is connected to
   `curr_node`.
3. Then loop through each node in `complement_edges` perform 3
   operation

   - Update distance if optimal
   - remove this node from undiscovered
   - ENQUEUE(Queue, this node)

Some things to note here,
If the initial graph is sparse, then the `undiscovered` will become empty very fast.
During implementation, use hashing to store edges in graph, this will make step 2 fast.

Heres the sample code:-

```
HashSet<Integer> adjList[];           // graph stored as adjancency list

public int[] calc_distance(int start){
        HashSet<Integer> undiscovered = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
            undiscovered.add(i);
        }

        int[] dist = new int[N+1];
        Arrays.fill(dist, Integer.MAX_VALUE/4);


        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(start);
        dist[start] = 0;

        while(!q.isEmpty() && undiscovered.size()>0){
            int curr = q.poll();

            LinkedList<Integer> complement_edges = new LinkedList<>();
            for(int child : undiscovered){
                if(!adjList[curr].contains(child)){
                    // curr and child is connected in complement
                    complement_edges.add(child);
                }
            }

            for(int child : complement_edges){
                if(dist[child]>(dist[curr]+1)){
                    dist[child] = dist[curr]+1;
                }
                // remove complement_edges from undiscovered
                undiscovered.remove(child);
                q.add(child);
            }
        }

        return dist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why we need this check "if(dist[child]>(dist[curr]+1))"